# Why got syntax error 'break' outside loop?

Tags: python

I have this code and I don't know why I get the error `Break outside loop`. Can you help me?

```
def TrackImage():
    recognizer = cv2.face_LBPHFaceRecognizer.create()
    recognizer.read('C:/Users/Jin/Anaconda3/envs/final/TrainingImageLabel/Trainner.yml')
    harcascadePath = ("C:/Users/Jin/Desktop/python opencv/opencv/build/etc/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
    faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(harcascadePath)
    df=pd.read_csv('StudentDetails/studentDetails.csv')
    cam=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
    col_names = ['Id','Name','Date','Time']
    attendance = pd.DataFrame(Columns = col_names)
    while True:
        ret, img = cam.read()
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces = detector.detectMultiScale(gray,1.3,5)
        for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
            cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
            Id, conf = recognizer.predict(gray[y:y+h, x:x+w])
            if (conf < 50):
                ts = time.time()
                date=datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                timeStamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%H:%M,%S')
                aa = df.loc[df['Id'] == Id]['Name'].values
                tt=str(Id)+"-"+aa
                attendance.loc[len(attendance)] = [Id,aa,date,timeStamp]
            else:
                Id='Unknown'
                tt=str(Id)
                if(conf>75):
                    noOfFile=len (os.listdir("ImagesUnknown"))+1
                    cv2.imwrite("ImagesUnknown\Image"+str(noOfFile)+".jpg",im[y:y+h,x:x+w])
                cv2.putText(im,str(tt),(x,y+h), font, 1 ,(255,255,255),2)
    attendance= attendance.drop_duplicates(subset=['Id'],keep='first')
    cv2.imshow('im',im)
    if(cv2.waitKey(1)==ord('q')):
        break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the last two line of your code. Where the `break` is out of any loop.

Put it in the specific loop, if you need it, otherwise remove it.

Comment: I remove it another error come out expected an indented block

Comment: If you remove it, you aslo need to process the `if` statement above it.

Comment: Now I got another error is     ret, img = cam.read()
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: You should check what the code is doing, before you do any action.

Comment: You remove the if and break just make the syntex is OK. It will not make what your're doing is OK. Check the  indent of the last four line of code.  Check which loop `while` or `for` the for line code should be.

Answer (score 2):

Because `break` is used only to forcibly exit a loop. In the code you published, you used `break` to exit an `if` condition, which is illegal. In your case, you can use `exit`.

[Break documentation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_break_statement.htm)